# Using SFINAE to detect existence of a function of void return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming, sfinae

Here's my situaition.  I'm trying to detect if a type has special methods utilized by [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), namley `to_json`.  Now I've seen the following solutions for free function checking with SFINAE:

- [Checking whether a function (not a method) exists in c++11 via templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319000/checking-whether-a-function-not-a-method-exists-in-c11-via-templates)
- [SFINAE: detect if class has free function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805807/sfinae-detect-if-class-has-free-function)

but these methods at least appear to rely on the *return type* of a function being void or not.  in the case of `to_json` the signature is as follows:

```
void to_json(json& j, const T& p);
```

which returns void... thus makes these methods fail (the second doesn't really work regardless since defining a custom wrapper for each type simply is not feasible).

I modified the first method, and as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include "json.hpp"

template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template<class... T> using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

    template<class T, class = void>
    struct is_jstreamable : std::false_type{};

    template<class T>
    struct is_jstreamable<T, void_t<decltype(to_json(std::declval<nlohmann::json &>(),
                                             std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};

struct Foo;

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_jstreamable<T>::value,
        void>::type
bar(){
    std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_jstreamable<T>::value,
        void>::type
bar(){
    std::cout << "It doesn't work!" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
//int does have conversion
    bar<int>();
//foo does not have conversion
    bar<Foo>();
}
```

it fails to work because its void type, the console returning:

```
It doesn't work!
It doesn't work!
```

instead of the expected

```
It works!
It doesn't work!
```

I saw a method for [determining if the return of a function *is void*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809992/detecting-void-method-in-c-template-metaprogramming) but I'm unsure of how to incorprate that as a solution of my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nlohmann::json has multiple ways to convert a given type to json. There is no `to_json` defined for `int`, so your type trait is working as specified.

Instead, detect if you can convert the type to a `nlohmann::json` object:

```
template <typename T>
using is_jstreamable = std::is_convertible<T, nlohmann::json>;
```

[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/eTR3pg)